# On the positivity of matrices

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, semidefinite-programming

For given $n$, the following $n\times n$ real matrix $M=M^{T}$ is called *positive*, if

$x^{T}M x\geq 0$

holds for all *non-negative* real $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$,
where $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)^T$.

Notice here, the definition of positive is not the same as usual defination of positive semidefinite.

Now the goal is to characterize the set of all such $M$. In particular, I would like to show the following statement:

Such $M$ can always written as positive combination of some positive semidefinite matrix and some $E_{ij}$s, where $E_{ij}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with the only non zero element 1 lies in the position $(i,j)$.

Comment: For symmetric 2-by-2-matrices the claim is easily checked directly: the assumption implies the diagonal entries to be nonnegative. Then either the off-diagonal entry is nonnegative, hence the Matrix has nonnegative entries, or the off-diagonal entry is negative, in which case the Matrix must be positive semidefinite. (Indeed then $x^TMx\ge 0$ whenever the entries of $x$ have opposite sign. Moreover by assumption $x^TMx\ge 0$ when the entries of $x$ have same sign.)

Comment: @ Will No, I do not!

Comment: IIRC, the minimal size for counterexample is $n=5$.

Comment: @Dima So, for $n<5$, my statement is true?

Comment: yes, it is true for $n\leq 4$. This was shown by P.Diananda in 1962 (Proc. Cambridge Phil.Soc., vol 58). The counterexample for n=5 (see my answer) is also from this text.

Comment: @Dima Can I have a link to the paper?

Comment: here it is:
http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0305004100036185

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Such matrices are called [copositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copositive_matrix) in the literature.

Moreover, the statement you want to show is known to be false. 
While I don't recall a counterexample right away,
an intuition for this is that it's NP-hard to check copositivity, but computationally easy to check the condition in your statement, via semidefinite programming, see e.g. this [text](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/pubs/files/Parrilo-Semidefinite%20programming%20based%20tests%20for%20matrix%20copositivity.pdf) by Pablo Parrilo.

EDIT: here is an explicit counterexample: the matrix
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1& 1& 1&-1\\
-1& 1&-1& 1& 1\\
 1&-1& 1&-1& 1\\
 1& 1&-1& 1&-1\\
-1& 1& 1&-1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is copositive, but not equal to the sum of a positive semidefinite matrix $P$ and a nonnegative matrix $N$.
It is taken from an old paper by P.Diananda in 1962 ([Proc. Cambridge Phil.Soc., vol 58(1962)](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0305004100036185)), where it is also shown that $n=5$ is minimal size for which one has such a counterexample.

A quick way to see that $M\neq P+N$ is as follows. First of all notice that $N$ can be assumed to have 0s on the main diagonal. This the condition $M=P+N$, that we want to bring to a contradiction, is equivalent to the existence of a positive semidefinite $P$ with all 1s on the diagonal, and satisfying the conditions $M_{ij}-P_{ij}\geq 0$, for all $1\leq i<j\leq 5$.

As $P$ is p.s.d., also for $i<j$ one has  $|P_{ij}|\leq 1$, as can be checked by computing
$x^\top P x$ for $x$ with $x_i=x_j=1$ and the remaining entries 0.  Thus $P_{ij}=-1$ for all $i,j$ s.t. $M_{ij}=-1$. Further, all $P$'s satisfying these condition form a convex set $\Sigma$.

Thus if $P\in\Sigma$ then $\Pi P\Pi^\top\in\Sigma$, for any permutation matrix $\Pi$ commuting with $M$, as $M=\Pi M\Pi^\top=P+N=\Pi (P+N)\Pi^\top$, i.e. $\Pi (P+N)\Pi^\top$ is another representation of $M$. Hence, by an averaging argument over the group $G$ of permutation matrices commuting with $M$, we can select $P$ to commute with all such $\Pi$'s. (More explicitly, take $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\Pi\in G}\Pi P\Pi^\top$.) It follows that there must exist $P$ of the form
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&-1& p& p&-1\\
-1& 1&-1& p& p\\
 p&-1& 1&-1& p\\
 p& p&-1& 1&-1\\
-1& p& p&-1& 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad -1\leq p\leq 1
$$
But none of such $P$'s are p.s.d., as its eigenvalues are
$$2 \, p - 1,
 -\frac{1}{2} \, p {\left(\sqrt{5} + 1\right)} - \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{5} + \frac{3}{2},
 \frac{1}{2} \, p {\left(\sqrt{5} - 1\right)} + \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{5} + \frac{3}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! How can one check the conditions in my statement?

Comment: This computational technique is called semi-definite programming.

Comment: How do you prove the example is indeed a counterexample?

Comment: @Hansen - see my latest edit for a proof and a reference.

Comment: I have two questions regarding your counterexample proof. 1) Why $|P_{ij}|\le 1$? 2) Could you please explicate in detail this paragraph "thus if P∈Σ then ΠPΠ⊤∈Σ, for any permutation matrix Π commuting with M. Hence, by an averaging argument, we can select P to commute with all such Π's. It follows that there must exist P of the form "? I understand the eigenvalue computation comes from $P$ being a circulant matrix.

Comment: @Hansen - see my latest edit.

Comment: Would the offending form of $P$ not follow directly from $|P_{ij}|\le 1$ and $P_{ij}=−1, \forall i,j \ni M_{ij}=−1$? Why do we need the averaging over group $G$ and the identification of $\Sigma$?

Comment: Also, are you saying the averaging over $G$ gives the offending matrix? Is that right?

Comment: What I am saying is: take an offending P, and average it over G. This gives a symmetric circulant matrix which is still offending, and which only depends on one parameter, $p$.

Comment: First of all, nice proof! Thank you, Dima. However, you have not answered my first question, that it seems the characterization of $P$, $|P_{ij}|\le 1$ etc. is enough to give you the offending form, and why you would need the averaging operation.

Comment: @Hansen: I don't see how you would complete a proof "by hand" without being able to reduce the number of parameters significantly.

Comment: I just realized that $P_{ij}$ are not necessarily the same where $M_{ij}=1$. That is why you need the averaging operation. But I still do not understand several points in the averaging argument. You say "It follows that there must exist P of the form". Is this $P$ the average over the group? How do you conclude the $P_{ij}$ all assume the same value $p$ rather than more than one values where $M_{ij}=1$?

Comment: One way to conclude that for $P$ being the average over an orbit all these $P_{ij}=p$, would be to note that $P$ commutes with all $\Pi\in G$. One can check that the algebra of all matrices commuting with $G$ coincides with the algebra of symmetric circulant matrices. Thus $P$ has the claimed form.

Comment: Would $G$ be large enough to smooth out a given $P$ so that $P_{ij}=p$? Why could $G$ not consist of only, as an extreme example, the identity matrix? Would you be so kind as to spell out all the details in the proof in your answer, since I am not familiar with this theory? Much obliged.

Comment: G depends on M only, and can be checked to be of size 10.

Comment: But my main question remains, i.e., why is $G$ able to guarantee that $P_{ij}=p$? Could you please add the details?

Comment: $G$ is able to guarantee that $P_{ij}=p$, as the dimension of the centraliser algebra (i.e. the vector space of matrices commuting with every element in $G$) is 3, which can be e.g. checked directly, or by computing the permutation character of $G$. All these things I don't define may be found in books on permutation groups, e.g. P.Cameron's http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Permutation_Groups.html?id=4bNj8K1omGAC

Comment: The vector space of matrices commuting with G has a basis {$I$,$\pi+\pi^4$,$\pi^2+\pi^3$}, where $\pi$ is the permutation matrix corresponding to the cyclic permutation (1,2,3,4,5). Thus $P$ will be a linear combination of these 3 matrices.